# AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'config'

Tags: python

**Edit:** [AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'config'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805856/attributeerror-bot-object-has-no-attribute-config?noredirect=1#comment78569999_45805856)

Despite the constant, persistent search for a solution, I still can not find a way to fix this error that is probably banal.

Error: `AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'config'`

application.py:

```
yaml = yaml.load(open("config.yml").read())
config = january.Config.from_yaml(yaml)

client = january.Bot(config)
[...]
```

january.py (code fragment in which the error is):

```
[...]
class Bot(Client):

    def __init__(self, config: Config):
        super().__init__(config.email, config.password)

        self.config = config

    def onLoggingIn(self, email=None):
        print(self.config.get_message("logging-in").format_value(email))
```

During testing and trying to execute the same from `application.py` everything works fine. The problem is only in the `Bot` class.
`Client` class is available [here](https://github.com/carpedm20/fbchat/blob/master/fbchat/client.py).

Any ideas? D:

Comment: Is the indentation of the line `self.config = config` accurate as shown?

Comment: I see that `Client.__init__()` calls `self.login()`.  Does `Bot` override the `login()` function, and if so, does it try to reference `self.config`?

Comment: `Is the indentation of the line self.config = config accurate as shown?` yes.

Comment: `I see that Client.__init__() calls self.login(). Does Bot override the login() function, and if so, does it try to reference self.config?`
Probably yes.

Comment: Then that's probably the cause.  `self.login()` is referencing `self.config` before it has been set.  The obvious fix is to set `self.config` before calling `super()`, however all the examples I've seen always call `super()` first before doing local stuff, so I don't know if that will work.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot! Greets :)